# select each author quotes and select tags from relations tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have a relations table for my tags, each author have quotes and each quote have their tags and hear is the tables:
**quotes**

```
+---------+----------+-------------+
|quotes_id| quotes   | author_id   |
+---------+----------+-------------+
|   10    |   text   |     2       | 
|   11    |   text   |     2       |
+---------+----------+-------------+
```

**tags**

```
+---------+----------+
|tag_id   | tag_name |
+---------+----------+
|   10    | words    | 
|   11    | words    |
+---------+----------+
```

**re_tags** its my relations table

```
+-----+----------+------------+-----------+
| id | tag_id   | quotes_id  | author_id |
+-----+----------+-------------+-----------+
| 3  |    2     |     10     |     2      | 
| 4  |    3     |     10     |     2      | 
+-----+----------+-------------+-----------+
```

what I want is select Quotes with author_id and then select the quotes tags from re_tags table and use that for select tags for each quote 
I used this query to select each author quotes and each quote tags but I get no result

```
$stmt = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM quotes 
LEFT JOIN re_tags ON quotes.quotes_id = re_tags.quotes_id
LEFT JOIN tags ON re_tags.tag_id = tags.tag_id
WHERE author_id= ".$_GET['id']." ");
```

I coding this query and its solved my problems

```
  $stmt = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM quotes 
 LEFT JOIN re_tags ON quotes.quotes_id = re_tags.quotes_id
 LEFT JOIN tags ON re_tags.tag_id = tags.tag_id 
 WHERE quotes.author_id= ".$_GET['id']." group by re_tags.quotes_id");
```

but still, I have another problem when I group by re_tags quotes_id I can only get **1 tag** but **1 quote** inclouds **many tags**

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use prepared statements.

Comment: What exactly keeps you from writing the query you are looking for?